# bash list file (ls) and find a number

Tags: bash, grep, ls

I have in my directory this files

```
ls -l /toto/
total 0
brw-rw---- 1 tata par 112, 24 Apr 16 13:08 file1
brw-rw---- 1 tata par 112, 23 Apr 16 13:08 file2
```

My bash have to verify that the number 112 is present for all lines

```
for f in $(ls -l /toto/);
do
fff=`grep "112" $f`
echo $fff
done

result:
grep: tata: No such file or directory
grep: 112: No such file or directory
grep: file1: No such file or directory
```

why? how ? Thanks

Comment: You can use find: find /toto/  -type f -size 112c -exec ls -lh {} \;

Comment: What if you have file `file112`?

Comment: Grepping the output of `ls -l` can produce false positives if `112` is present in the name of a file, f.e.?

Comment: Are you trying to make sure that they are all block special files with major device type == 112 ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to produce? A `yes`/`no` result? A list of files that have a size different than `112`? Something else?

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs,  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 for the 3 common problems with your script.

Answer (score 2):

The files listed in your question are block devices (the `b` as the first character in the permissions block tells that).

This means `112` and `24` are the major and the minor version of the first file, in decimal notation.

The Unix command [`stat`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html) can be used to produce a file listing that uses a custom format (as opposed to `ls` that knows only a couple of fixed formats).

The command line you need is:

```
stat --format "%t %n" /toto/*
```

The [`%t` format specifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html) lists the major version of a device file, in hexadecimal notation. `%n` lists the file name (we use it for debug).

`112` in hexadecimal is `0x70`. The command above should print:

```
70 file1
70 file2
```

Now you can pipe it through `grep '^70 '` and then to `wc -l` to count the number of lines that start with `70` (`70` followed by a space):

```
stat --format "%t %n" /toto/* | grep '^70 ' | wc -l
```

If you want to know if all files in the `/toto/` directory have major version `112` then you can compare the number produced by the command above against the number produced by the next command (it produces the number of files and directories in the `/toto/` directory)`

```
ls -1 /toto/ | wc -l
```

If you want to also know what files have a different major version then you can run this command:

```
stat --format "%t %n" /toto/* | grep -v '^70 '
```

It filters out the lines that do not start with `^70` and displays only the files that have a different major version (and their major version in hex).

If it doesn't display anything then all the files in the `/toto/` directory has major version `112`.

**Remark:** the command above will also list the regular files and directories and other files that are not devices (only the devices has versions).